# Compress the data passed in JSON

Tags: json, jsonp

I dont know whether i am asking valid question
My problem is i want to send large data from one application to another for which i am using JSONP to pass data to handler file which stores it in database.As the data is large i am dividing it in chunks and passing the packets in loop, the more the number of packets the more time it takes to pass complete data which ultimately results in performance issue.(FYI my web server is bit slow)
Is there any way by which i can compress my data and send it at a time rather than sending it in packets.
OR 
Any other way by which i can pass my data(large data) from application to another.
Need this ASAP
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to check out the HPack algorithm (https://github.com/WebReflection/json.hpack/wiki) and CJSON algorithm  (http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=104), the HPack algorithm being more efficient than the CJSON algortihm according to http://web-resource-optimization.blogspot.com/2011/06/json-compression-algorithms.html

Comment: It would help to have some sample data.